# Динамичноее создание java SWT элементов

Tags: java, swt

позволяет ли `swt` во время выполнения программы добавлять `gui` элементы? например нажал на кнопку и создался `Label` с каким-нибудь текстом     upd: код как я делаю.

```
public class PrimaryWin {

public static void main(String[] args){
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setSize(500, 500);

        Label l2 = new Label(shell, SWT.VERTICAL);
        Button save = new Button(shell, SWT.VERTICAL);
        Label l1 = new Label(shell, SWT.VERTICAL);
        Button addScript = new Button(shell, SWT.VERTICAL);

        addNewLine(shell);

        save.setText("save");
        addScript.setText("add script");

        addScript.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                addNewLine(shell);
            }
        });

        GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
        gridLayout.numColumns = 4;

        shell.setLayout(gridLayout);
        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
    public static void addNewLine(Shell shell){
        Text id = new Text(shell, SWT.VERTICAL);
        Text rid = new Text(shell, SWT.VERTICAL);
        Combo method = new Combo(shell, SWT.VERTICAL);
        method.setItems(new String[]{"test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"});
        Text args = new Text(shell, SWT.VERTICAL);
    }
}
```

Comment: Создать нет, поскольку каждый раз возникает проблема с выделением памяти и заданием имени. Говоря обывательски, имя ведь нельзя создать строкой, которая будет меняться динамически. Однако вы можете сделать их активными по нажатии кнопки.

Comment: @Bulbum, Не обзательно указывать имена при создании объектов, в javaFX я это спокойно провернул, но javaFX мне не подходит. Я подправил немного статью и показал как это можно делать, но  это почему не работает если метод вызывать во время работы программы, т.е. например при нажатии кнопки

Comment: да. это позволяет любой GUI фреймворк. что именно не работает?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman, при нажатии на кнопку, во время исполнения программы новые gui элементы не добавлятся. Мб там окно надо обновить как нибудь или типо того?

Comment: добавьте в вопрос [mcve]

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman обновил, чекай

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы забыли вызвать перерисовку (перекомпоновку) окна

```
addScript.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        addNewLine(shell);
        // перекомпоновать окно
        shell.layout();
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! все заработало. Я уж чуть swing не начал изучать

Comment: @naughtyBit у swing зависимостей меньше. В этом плане он проще.